# How to execute code after trigger_error(..., E_USER_WARNING) in unit test (PHPUnit)?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have code like this:

```
class ToBeTested
{
  function simpleMethod($param)
  {
    if(0 === $param)
    {
      trigger_error("Param is 0!", E_USER_WARNING);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

and test for this code:

```
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   function testSimpleMethod()
   {
     $toBeTestedObject = new ToBeTested();
     $this->assertFalse($toBeTestedObject->simpleMethod(0));
   }
}
```

I know how to test, if the error is triggered (`$this->setExpectedException()`), but I don't know how to execute the code after `trigger_error()` function.

Remember that in PHPUnit `E_USER_WARNING` is not converted into `PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning` (which can be disabled), but it is converted into `PHPUnit_Framework_Error` (which can't be disabled).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of those places where you are 'officially' allowed to use the @ operator :)

Make one test to check the return value, another test to check if the warning gets triggered. And by the way, I'd suggest you *do* test if the warning is triggered.

```
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   function testSimpleMethodReturnValue()
   {
     $toBeTestedObject = new ToBeTested();
     $this->assertFalse(@$toBeTestedObject->simpleMethod(0));
   }

   /**
    * @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error
    */
   function testSimpleMethodEmitsWarning() {
     $toBeTestedObject = new ToBeTested();
     $toBeTestedObject->simpleMethod(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It really looks as a good example to use @ character. :)

Comment: Is this still considered to be the proper approach for testing `E_USER_WARNING`?

Comment: @tereško Yes. It's still the only somewhat sane way I'm aware of doing this. It might make sense to _first_ test the warning and then the error so in case of E_FATALs the error suppression is off. But `xdebug.scream` is also always there :)

Comment: php.net docs: [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Comment: As from phpunit 8.5, you can `expectWarning`, instead

Answer (score 3):

What you should be using is `set_error_handler()` ([link](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)) and `restore_error_handler()` which lets you set a function to deal with errors of a given type. It also has the added bonus of giving you a place to test the warning at the same time.

So, something like this:

```
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   function testSimpleMethod()
   {
     set_error_handler(array($this, '_handleWarnedMethod'), E_USER_WARNING);

     $toBeTestedObject = new ToBeTested();
     $this->assertFalse($toBeTestedObject->simpleMethod(0));

     restore_error_handler();
   }

   private function _handleWarnedMethod($errno, $errstr)
   {
      $this->assertEquals(E_USER_WARNING, $errno);
      $this->assertEquals('Param is 0!', $errstr);
   }

}
```

As always, error suppression isn't the best idea :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that in PHPUnit 3.4.15 there is `PHPUnit_Util_ErrorHandler` class with `handleError` method which is executed when any error occurs. For error like `E_USER_*` this method always throws `PHPUnit_Framework_Error`, so execution of the rest of code is stopped.

The only way to prevent this is to disable user errors reporting, I think. It could be done like this:

```
class SimpleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   function testSimpleMethod()
   {
      $toBeTestedObject = new ToBeTested();

      // disable user errors reporting
      $oldReportingLevel = error_reporting();
      error_reporting($oldReportingLevel ^ (E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_USER_NOTICE));

      // check the condition
      $this->assertFalse($toBeTestedObject->simpleMethod(0));

      // recover old error reporting level
      error_reporting($oldReportingLevel);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 9 years later, and this question still comes up regularly.

You can use [Netsilik/BaseTestCase](https://packagist.org/packages/netsilik/base-test-case) (MIT License) to get extended functionality to assert errors/warnings are triggered as expected:

`composer require netsilik/base-test-case`

Testing for a `E_WARNING`:

```
<?php
namespace Tests;

class MyTestCase extends \Netsilik\Testing\BaseTestCase
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $this->_convertNoticesToExceptions  = false;
        $this->_convertWarningsToExceptions = false;
        $this->_convertErrorsToExceptions   = true;
    }

    public function test_whenWarningTriggered_weCanTestForIt()
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $foo->bar();

        self::assertErrorTriggered(E_WARNING, 'The warning string');
    }
}
```