# How can I mock outputting messages to the error log with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, automated-tests, error-logging

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312777/1370106) it mentions using `expectOutputString()` to, well, expect output strings in PHPUnit.

I also need to do sort of the counterpart of this, which is to tell a mock to output a string.

I was previously using `$mock->will($this->throwException(Exception('foo'))` to have my mock throw an exception but now instead of throwing an exception I need it to log the error and NOT re-throw the exception, which means I need my mock to output a string just as `error_log()` does in the method I'm trying to mock, so that my test can expect the string.

Does this make sense? Is it possible to do? Does PHPUnit offer a way to do it?

Comment: php_error()? Do you mean error_log()?

Comment: yes I do. It's been a long day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the testability point of view, it's always better to abstract the error logging into a class. If you make direct calls to `error_log()` you will have difficulties checking the calls made.

**If you can't refactor** your code and use a class for logging errors, you could try setting a custom error handler that will store the messages in some place, and then check those messages at the test, after the relevant call.

But if you can, **it's better to create a class with methods that abstract native php error logging**. This class will be a dependency of the class under test. You can either pass it as a constructor mandatory argument, or have the class create it automatically, but allow to set it externally. Obviously, in the test you would inject a mock of that "ErrorLogger" class with expectations